# How to switch two divs in html

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have two div's that are overlapping each other.I want to swap two div's. Without doing any changes in code.
How It is possible to swap two div's?

Comment: Please look at: [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Swap in which way?

Comment: _Without doing any changes in code_ i don't see any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can use Z-index to solve this problem

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The z-index Property</h1>

<img src="w3css.gif" width="100" height="140">

<p>Because the image has a z-index of -1, it will be placed behind the heading.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox` ordering to accomplish this.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order):

> The **order** `CSS` property sets the order to lay out an item in a flex or
>   grid container. Items in a container are sorted by ascending order
>   value and then by their source code order.

Have a look at this demo. Open it in 'Full page' mode and resize the screen to less than `400px` so that the boxes begin to overlap. Using ordering, I've swapped, or switched, the `div`s without the need for any `JavaScript`.

[image]

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container > * {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container > *::after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1.5em;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: black;  
}

.left {
  background-color: green;  
}

.left::after {
  content: 'left';
}

.right {
  background-color: blue;
}

.right::after {
  content: 'right';
}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .left {
    order: 1;    
  }
  
  .left::after {
    content: 'right';
  }
  
  .right::after {
    content: 'left';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rv7gmc1k/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to swap the visibility of the div's? With **z-index** you can put 1 div above the other.

```css
.red, .blue {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  z-index: 1;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```